# Implementation of an Stack without Linked Lists in C

Tags: beginner, c, stack

I'm a beginning C programmer. As an exercise, I have attempted to implement a stack of strings in C. This is my first real exercise working with pointers. I looked at some other similar posts on here, and read through the comments. It seems that most individuals have chosen to do this by using linked lists, whereas I've just created an `ArrayStack`.

Maybe it would have been better to go the linked list route. Nonetheless, this is how I did it. I'm hoping there's not any glaring errors, but I'm sure there will be.

Also, question: I have a variable for the number of slots available in the array, which is used to determine when more memory needs to be allocated. But it would seem to me that I can use sizeof on the array, and `sizeof` on a single pointer in the array, and use division to get the number of slots, thus eliminating a variable. Would this be a better approach?

**stack.h**

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct stringstack {
    int count;
    int slots;
    char** stack;
} stringstack;

void * makestack(void);
void push(struct stringstack* ptr, char stringtext[]);
char * pop(struct stringstack* ptr);
char * peek(struct stringstack* ptr);
int isempty(struct stringstack* ptr);
void destroy(struct stringstack* ptr);
```

**stack.c**

```
#include "stack.h"

/* Function creates a new stringstack object and returns a pointer to it */
void * makestack(void) {
    stringstack *ptr = (stringstack *) malloc(sizeof(stringstack));
    ptr->count = 0;
    ptr->slots = 1;
    ptr->stack = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char*));
    return ptr;
}

/* Pushes a string onto the top of a stack */
void push(struct stringstack* ptr, char stringtext[]) {
    ptr->count++;
    if (ptr->count == ptr->slots) /* Allocate more space if necessary */
        ptr->stack = (char **) realloc(ptr->stack, sizeof(char *)*((ptr->slots*=2)+1));
    char *stringptr = (char *) malloc(sizeof(stringtext));
    stringptr = stringtext;
    *(ptr->stack + ptr->count) = stringptr;
}

/* Removes the top item from the stack, returning a pointer to it */
char * pop(struct stringstack* ptr) {
    if (ptr->count>0)
        return *(ptr->stack + ptr->count--);
    return NULL;
}

/* Returns a pointer to top item from stack but does not pop it */
char * peek(struct stringstack* ptr) {
    if (ptr->count>0)
        return *(ptr->stack + ptr->count);
    return NULL;
}

/* Returns whether a stringstack contains at least one string */
int isempty(struct stringstack* ptr) {
    return (ptr->count == 0);
}

/* Frees a stringtack from memory */
void destroy(struct stringstack* ptr) {
    size_t n;
    for (n = 0; n <= ptr->count; n++ )
        free(ptr->stack+n);
    free(ptr->stack);
    free(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! That looks like an interesting implementation. I hope you get good reviews!

Answer (score 10):

- `makestack` should return a `struct stringstack *` instead of `void *`.
- `malloc` and `realloc` may fail. Check their return values.
- `push` doesn't *copy* the string (it only makes a redundant copy of the pointer). It is OK as long as you can guarantee that the string parameter has a lifetime long enough. Consider a scenario:

  ```
  void foo(struct stringstack * stack)
  {
      char bar[] = "aaa";
      push(stack, bar);
  }
  ```

  Upon the return, `bar` disappears, and the stack entry points to the pretty random place in the application stack. Do not expect to have "aaa" there.

  To actually copy the string, do

  ```
   *(ptr->stack + ptr->count) = strdup(stringtext);
  ```

  which may introduce other problems in interacting with client (who owns the string after `peek`?). Unfortunately, C doesn't offer a clean solution.
- You may want to shrink the stack when `ptr->count` hits the low watermark of `ptr->slots`.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Yeah that's kind of a big error on my part for the push function... I knew there would be one!

Thank you (for the other stuff as well.)

Answer (score 6):

First, to answer your question about `sizeof`, run this simple test code:

```
char * str_1    = "foo1";
char   str_2[5] = "foo2";

printf("%zu\n", sizeof(str_1)); // 8 or 4
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(str_2)); // 5
```

On my machine, it prints 8 and 5. This is because `sizeof` behaves differently when applied to an array vs a *pointer* to an array. If you apply `sizeof` to an array which its size is **known at compile time**, `sizeof` will produce the size in bytes of such array. If you apply it to a pointer to an array of variable size, allocated either dynamically or by acquiring a pointer to a static array, `sizeof` will produce the size in bytes of the pointer, hence the 8 for the first `printf` call (on my machine pointers are 8 bytes wide). So no, you can't use `sizeof` to infer the size of a dynamically allocated array.

### Code review:

You don't need to include `<stdio.h>` in the header. It would be better to only include it in the implementation. Also, your header lack an [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

---

The `stringstack` implementation could be hidden. If you declare an opaque/incomplete type in the header, the definition of the struct could go in the `.c` file. That would make it hidden to outside users, so you would also have to provide methods to get the stack size, etc. Hiding implementation details is generally desirable, since it makes the code more robust to change. So you might consider this approach. Example:

**stack.h:**

```
typedef struct stringstack;

/* All the function prototypes... */
```

**stack.c:**

```
typedef struct stringstack {
    int count;
    int slots;
    char** stack;
} stringstack;

/* The code... */
```

---

`makestack()` should return a pointer to `stringstack`, not `void*`. Also, since you have declared the type with a `typedef struct`, you can omit the `struct` tag when referring to `stringstack`.

---

Personally, I find `tightlypacked` names hard to read. Consider using `snake_case` for the multi-word function names. Also, calling the stack type `StringStack` to differentiate it from the name of a function wouldn't be a bad idea.

---

Read-only function parameters of pointer type should be `const`, to document the intent of the function. Since you only read the string in `push()`, the ideal function signature would be:

```
void push(struct stringstack* ptr, const char stringtext[])
```

Functions that only query the stack, like `isempty()` could also take the stack pointer by `const stringstack*`.

---

Use assertions to enforce invariants. The invariant of every function is that the stack pointer is not null. You should [`assert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/) that on function entry to ensure a null pointer is trapped right away.

Comment: Hm, yeah. You're right about the sizeof thing. I knew that wouldn't work, but for some reason I brainfarted. -.-

Thank you for all of your suggestions. I have a bit of reading to do (assert, include guarding.) But I understand the other suggestions, and I like them.

Answer (score 4):

I've modified your code with some cleanups.  My comments are in "//" style comments to explain the changes.  The main things I changed:

1. The stack now uses array index [0].  Previously, that index was just wasted.
2. The code uses `const` when appropriate.
3. The code uses `ptr->stack[i]` instead of `ptr->stack + i`.
4. `struct stringstack` was replaced with just `stringstack`.
5. An allocated copy is made of each string pushed.
6. The destroy function had a bug in it which is now fixed.

Here is the modified code:

```
/* Function creates a new stringstack object and returns a pointer to it */
// Return stringstack * instead of void *.
stringstack * makestack(void) {
    stringstack *ptr = (stringstack *) malloc(sizeof(stringstack));
    ptr->count = 0;
    ptr->slots = 1;
    ptr->stack = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char*));
    return ptr;
}

/* Pushes a string onto the top of a stack */
// Use "const" whenever an argument will not be modified.
// Use "stringstack" instead of "struct stringstack" since you have the typedef.
void push(stringstack* ptr, const char *stringtext) {
    if (ptr->count == ptr->slots) {/* Allocate more space if necessary */
        // Separate ptr->slots *= 2 to its own line for readability.
        // No need for "ptr->slots + 1" now that we are using all the slots.
        ptr->slots *= 2;
        ptr->stack = (char **) realloc(ptr->stack, sizeof(char *)*ptr->slots);
    }
    // Use [] instead of + for indexing.  Also note the ptr->count++ which
    // matches with the --ptr->count in the pop() function.  The stack is
    // 0-based instead of 1-based so it doesn't waste an array slot.
    ptr->stack[ptr->count++] = strdup(stringtext);
}

/* Removes the top item from the stack, returning a pointer to it */
char * pop(stringstack* ptr) {
    // Handle error cases upfront.  (This is stylistic, so it's up to you).
    if (ptr->count == 0)
        return NULL;
    return ptr->stack[--ptr->count];
}

/* Returns a pointer to top item from stack but does not pop it */
char * peek(const stringstack* ptr) {
    if (ptr->count == 0)
        return NULL;
    return ptr->stack[ptr->count-1];
}

/* Returns whether a stringstack contains at least one string */
int isempty(const stringstack* ptr) {
    return (ptr->count == 0);
}

/* Frees a stringstack from memory */
void destroy(stringstack* ptr) {
    size_t n;
    // Previously, you were freeing ptr->stack[0] which was never allocated.
    // With the new 0-based stack, it is correct to free ptr->stack[0], but
    // not ptr->stack[ptr->count].  So I modified the for loop.
    for (n = 0; n < ptr->count; n++ )
        free(ptr->stack[n]);
    free(ptr->stack);
    free(ptr);
}
```

Also, you should check the return value of `malloc` and `realloc`.  I didn't make the change in my example here because I didn't know what you wanted your code to do if that happened.

Comment: Note that `strdup()` is POSIX but not standard C.

Comment: Thank you, reading your edits has been very useful to me.